# Linq group key is not unique

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

I have following codes, which causes `System.ArgumentException`:

> An item with the same key has already been added. Key:PH

```
_HotelsByCountry = db.Hotels
   .GroupBy(hotel => hotel.CountryCode)
   .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.ToList());
```

Does it mean *group key* is **not** unique when use `GroupBy` operation?

**Update**  `hotel.CountryCode` is type of `string`.

**Update**  `CountryCode` is foreign key.

**Update**  sql server and ef core 2.0

**Update** the following code works

```
_HotelsByCountry = db.Hotels
   .GroupBy(hotel => hotel.CountryCode.Trim())
   .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.ToList());
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171463/discussion-on-question-by-bo-yee-woods-linq-group-key-is-not-unique).

Comment: And what is the database (sql server or someting else) and collation?

Answer (score 2):

You can Use [ToLookup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup(v=vs.110).aspx)  Instead

```
var x = db.Hotels.ToLookup(hotel => hotel.CountryCode);
```

For those how wants to know code behind `ToLookup` you can check [Microsoft Github repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs)

Basically `ToLookup` uses `EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default` to compare keys and do what you should do manually when using group by and to dictionary.

I'm not sure, but linqpad not show any sign of converting ToLookup to SQL query so i think it's excuted inmemory

Comment: This solution has the same problem.

Comment: I try this solution, it works well. But I just want to know why my code cannot work.

Comment: @BoYeeWoods can you post the SQL code that gets generated when you execute that query?

Comment: @AleksandrIvanov i added link to code, check it out

Comment: @MasihAkbari - Is ToLookup function execute on inmemory or on SQL?

Comment: @user1672994 I'm not sure, but linqpad not show any sign of converting ToLookup to SQL query so i think it's excuted inmemory

Comment: I'm doubting the same.